# Select clauses in event filter

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have two questions concerning events.
(I am not sure if they are concerned with `Milo` (which I am using right now) or OPCUA in general.):

1)
I created an `EventFilter` which is used in a `MonitoringParameters` object.

The `selectClauses` of the filter is an array of `SimpleAttributeOperands` each of which has the `NodeId` of my `EventType` plus the `QualifiedName` of the properties I want to retrieve.

The event type and it's properties have `ns=2`, but weirdly I have to specify the qualified names like `QualifiedName(ns=0, property_name)`.

This works, but I found this rather confusing. Specifying `ns=2` yields null values, which leads to my second question:

2)  In the same setup. When I add a `SimpleAttribute` referring to a qualified name which does not exist on the server I receive a null value. I would have expected that this throws an error instead (like in `SQL`).

Any help is appreciated very much.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first scenario you describe sounds like a bug in the server.

The second sounds correct. You may have received an indication that the field didn't exist in your select clause results at the time you created it.

The spec has this to say about it:

> A null value is returned in the corresponding event field in the Publish response if the selected field is not part of the Event or an error was returned in the selectClauseResults of the EventFilterResult.

Comment: Thank you very much, it‘s appreciated a lot! The server is based on open62541.

Comment: @user_11437 what was the namespace index of the qualified name on the browse name attribute of those event types in ns2?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the right thing to look at, it's set to 0.

Comment: Ok, in that case I would say it’s unusual, but also correct behavior of the server for scenario 1. Unless those property names are inherited from an event type from ns=0, in which case everything is fine :)